# How can I get the version of the AIR runtime in my AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, air

In a Flex web application, you can print the version of the flash player that is being used by using:

```
var version:String = Capabilities.version
```

According to [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version), this should return the flash player or AIR runtime version, but it does not in my testing. I keep getting the flash player version when running in AIR.

Is there a way to get the AIR version? I am running on AIR 3.2

(I want to display the AIR runtime version in the about box of my application for troubleshooting purpose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will [this work for you](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5f3b-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cc6)?

To quote:

> The NativeApplication object has a runtimeVersion property, which is
>   the version of the runtime in which the application is running (a
>   string, such as "1.0.5"). The NativeApplication object also has a
>   runtimePatchLevel property, which is the patch level of the runtime (a
>   number, such as 2960). The following code uses these properties:
>
> air.trace(air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion); 
>   air.trace(air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimePatchLevel);

Comment: My about window is in common code between the web version and the air version of my app and does not have direct access to `NativeApplication`, but I worked around it as follows:

    if(org.springextensions.actionscript.util.Environment.isAIR)
    {
        var version:String = ClassUtils.forName( "flash.desktop.NativeApplication" )["nativeApplication"]["runtimeVersion"];
    }